# Convert Id in ViewModel to ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I have a wpf ResourceDictionary which is hosting several more or less complex xaml "icons", and UserControls that are supposed to host these icons. The idea is to have a public property Id of type integer in the ViewModel of the control. I would like to now take this Id property and convert it to the ResourceDictionary entry. I am sure this is a pretty standard use case, but for some reason I’m stuck.

This the imlementation in the UserControl

```xml
                <Border Margin="4" Grid.Row="0" 
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource EyGrayTint1Brush}" 
                        BorderThickness="0.5">
                    <Viewbox>
                                    <!--Template="{StaticResource WelcomeIcon}"-->
                        <ContentControl Template="{Binding Id, Converter={local:IdToIconConverter}}"

                                        Margin="20"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Border>
```

This is the Converter

```cs
    public class IdToIconConverter : BaseValueConverter<IdToIconConverter>
    {
        public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //Here I would like to do the conversion
            switch ((int)value)
            {
                case 1:

                    return null;
                case 2:

                    return null;
                default:
                    Debugger.Break();
                    return null;
            }

        }
```

Is there any way I can assign the static resource via this conversion method?

Comment: Instead of an integer property `Id`, you can have a string property `IconName` which can hold the resource key of the icon. Then, use an `Image` in the view and set its `Source` property to the icon name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by -->  using Application.Current.Resources["ResourceKey"]
The resources are merged in the App.xaml

```
public class IdToIconConverter : BaseValueConverter<IdToIconConverter>
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ControlTemplate controlTemplate = new ControlTemplate();

        switch ((int)value)
        {
            case 1:
                controlTemplate = (ControlTemplate)Application.Current.Resources["WelcomeIcon"];
                return controlTemplate;

            default:
                //Debugger.Break();
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

For easier use, here my BaseValueConverter class

```
/// <summary>
/// A base value converter that allows direct XAML usage
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of this value converter</typeparam>
public abstract class BaseValueConverter<T> : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    where T : class, new()
{
    #region Private Members

    /// <summary>
    /// A single static instance of this value converter
    /// </summary>
    private static T mConverter = null;

    #endregion

    #region Markup Extension Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Provides a static instance of the value converter 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceProvider">The service provider</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return mConverter ?? (mConverter = new T());
    }

    #endregion

    #region Value Converter Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// The method to convert one type to another
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <param name="targetType"></param>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    /// <param name="culture"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public abstract object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);

    /// <summary>
    /// The method to convert a value back to it's source type
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <param name="targetType"></param>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    /// <param name="culture"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public abstract object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);

    #endregion
```

**  I hope this can help others. bg**

Comment: As per SO rules, don't forget to link the original creator of shared code. Source code here https://github.com/angelsix/fasetto-word/blob/develop/Source/Fasetto.Word/ValueConverters/BaseValueConverter.cs and video of me creating it here https://youtu.be/JU9Ai0hpBUI?t=340

Comment: oh sorry, exactly... I'm just learning how to use stack overflow. How do I link the creator to the answer? @angelsix